# CiviRules not triggering event reached date

Tags: civirules

The user wants to send a recurring email - twice a week on successive days. So I set up a recurring event and then added a CiviRule with the trigger 'Event date reached'.  The event didn't trigger because of the following crash - it doesn't have any participants, could this be the problem?

```
SELECT `p`.*
        FROM `civicrm_participant` `p`
        INNER JOIN `civicrm_event` `e` ON `e`.`id` = `p`.`event_id`
        LEFT JOIN `civirule_rule_log` `rule_log` ON `rule_log`.entity_table = 'civicrm_participant' AND `rule_log`.entity_id = p.id AND `rule_log`.`contact_id` = `p`.`contact_id` AND DATE(`rule_log`.`log_date`) = DATE(NOW())  AND `rule_log`.`rule_id` = %3
        WHERE DATE(`e`.`start_date`) = CURDATE()
        AND `rule_log`.`id` IS NULL
        AND `e`.`event_type_id` = 12
        AND `p`.`contact_id` NOT IN (
          SELECT `rule_log2`.`contact_id`
          FROM `civirule_rule_log` `rule_log2`
          WHERE `rule_log2`.`rule_id` = %3 AND DATE(`rule_log2`.`log_date`) = DATE(NOW()) and `rule_log2`.`entity_table` IS NULL AND `rule_log2`.`entity_id` IS NULL
        ) [nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '%3
        WHERE DATE(`e`.`start_date`) = CURDATE()
        AND `rule...' at line 4]
```

I'd like to understand how to get this working, and also if anyone has a suggestion of an alternative way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue would indeed be that there are no participants, so therefore no events joined and an empty start_date. Can you try with a participant?

If the issue persists can you please report it as a bug on the Civirules extension page (https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions?utf8=%E2%9C%93&filter=civirules)? Would fixing it be possible for you?

Comment: I tried with participants, but got a different crash.  Issue added as you suggested. I don't have the PHP skills to fix, sorry.

Comment: No worries...might well be that others run into the same problems so it gets fixed. Or you'd have to wait until the next CiviRules sprint that CiviCooP does (not scheduled yet)